# Insert to sql server by entity error utf-8

Tags: entity-framework

I'm try insert this row to my table

```
student (
     id (int)
    ,name (nvarchar)
)
```

But when I insert this value `(1,"bơ")` to `student` result in my database is
`(1,"bo?")`

this is my code

```
public bool Insert() {
    Admin_KX_MainDbEntities db = new Admin_KX_MainDbEntities();
    student student = new student() {
        id = 1,
        name = "bơ"
    };

    db.students.add(student);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving this value to verify? Are you sure this isn't just a matter of the tool/app you are using to view the data?

Comment: I use sql management to see that value and when I take that row, my result is (1,bo?)

Comment: Okay, next step would be to try `INSERT INTO student (id,name) VALUES (1, N'bơ')` to see if your table can handle it.

Comment: yep, I try it. But I want use entity. Thank you